# Pulling historical options closing data given strike, expiration and date

Tags: excel, bloomberg

I have a column of an option type I want(either call or put), a column for the date that I want the closing price of the option for,the option expiration date and the option strike. I want to find the option price on close given this information.

I wrote the formula below to try and find the price of the 3600 call on 3/8/19 with an expiration of 12/20/19 but it gives me an #N/A connection error.

=BDP("SX5E  12/20/19 C3600","px_last","03/08/2019","03/08/2019")

I expected to get what I described above but got an #N/A error

Comment: It's saying that you are not logged in on the Bloomberg terminal or that the bbcomm.exe process is not running.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in retrieving data that is historical (non current), then you would be better served by using the **BDH** formula, instead of **BDP**, which will give you the current value.

Perhaps this may help you

`=BDH("SX5E 12/20/19 C3600 Index","px_last","03/08/2019")` .

Notice how I added "Index" to the security name, to make it valid.